# Can not share data between controllers AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

Hi I`m new in AngularJS.
This is my index.html file
http://clip2net.com/s/3oknPG6

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Angular route</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
         <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <style>
        body {
            padding: 20px;
        }
        </style>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is app.js file:

```
angular.module("app", ["ui.router"])


.config(function config($stateProvider){
        $stateProvider.state("index", {
            url:"",
            controller: "FirstCtrl as first",
            templateUrl: "templates/first.html"
        })
    })

.controller("FirstCtrl", function FirstCtrl(){
            var first = this;
            first.greeting = "First";
        });
```

and first.html file:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="first.greeting"/>
    <div ng-class="first.greeting">{{first.greeting}}</div>
```

I can not get data in the view, please help me to solve this issue. Also I`m getting this error: Cannot read property 'isDefined' of undefined.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14168699/4161269

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi That is bit advance level stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading your 'ui-router' dependancy twice in your index.html. Maybe that is the problem? Just load your ui router after you have included angular.min.js.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with configuration...

```
controller: "FirstCtrl as first"
```

There is a controllerAs field that you can use. Try this:

```
controller: "FirstCtrl"
controllerAs: "first"
```

That should hopefully fix the issue around "isDefined" of undefined. Angular will literally be looking for a controller named "FirstCtrl as first".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What is `<script src="js/main.js"></script>`and also
 `<script src="app/app.js"></script>`and also you have loaded ui-router twice, remove 
`<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>`
also i am not sure what you are trying to achieve in your view first.html file by writing

```
ng-class="first.greeting"
```

The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.
[More Info on ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)